# Using SqlFrom("SELECT * FROM Table")

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

In my app the following code results in "InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid." error.

```
var rsq = db.Set<Reservations>().FromSql("SELECT * FROM Reservation");
```

When researching, I found out that this is due to **wrong order of columns** in the database. I.e. I had two columns that were created by one of migrations, added as last columns to the database, and apparently FromSql() reads columns in an order they came and ignores column names.

When columns order match the member definition in Reservation class, everything works fine.

Is this intended behavior of EF7?

Comment: Well, apparently. You better ask them.

Comment: Just order the columns in your select statement, SELECT * is completely brittle anyway

Comment: If I select less then all columns in this SQL statement, EF end up with an exception. So I'm forced by EF to list all the columns anyway, and if I list them here, I will need to modify the query every time I add new field to the data model.